# Non blocking select for inotify

Tags: c++, multithreading

I try to use inotify in c++ inside a thread
but the select is blocking, so I can never get outside the thread when my application exits

how I create the inotify watch

```
fd=inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
// checking for error
if ( fd < 0 ) 
    log->Print("Could not init files listener");
else
{
    // use select watch list for non-blocking inotify read
    FD_ZERO( &watch_set );
    FD_SET( fd, &watch_set );

    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // watch directory for any activity and report it back to me 
    int wd=inotify_add_watch(fd,folder.c_str(),IN_ALL_EVENTS);

    // add wd and directory name to Watch map
    watch.insert( -1, folder, wd );

    // start listening thread
    run(FilesListener::threadBootstrap);
}
```

here is the function called in my thread loop

```
void FilesListener::refresh()
{
    char buffer[1024];

    // select waits until inotify has 1 or more events.
    // select needs the highest fd (+1) as the first parameter.
    select( fd+1, &watch_set, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    // Read event(s) from non-blocking inotify fd (non-blocking specified in inotify_init1 above).
    int length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
    if ( length < 0 ) 
        log->Print("Could not read inotify file descriptor");
    else
    {  
    ....
```

Comment: "can never get outside the thread" What does it mean? `select` is *designed* to block until you can read or write. It can also be used to check whether you have something to read, without blocking, but you are not checking what `select` returns, so that's obviously not what you want. You can just remove the call to `select` altogether.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with select?

Comment: I removed select and it works fine, still wonder why use "select" unless one write a program that will be killed by CTRL+Z

Comment: actualy I found a tutorial a while ago, so I dont know why the author used select...I used select back in the day I was writing a fast socket server to avoid polling if I remember well

Comment: select() can receive a struct timeval to timeout if no activity happens in the file descriptor: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-ubuntu-inotify/#tips-for-using-inotify

Answer (score 2):

Check https://github.com/paulorb/FileMonitor it has an easy interface for achieving what you want. It is a port of windows API to Linux using inotify.

Example:

```
#include "FileMonitor.hpp"

int main(void)
{

    int m_EventID = FindFirstChangeNotification("/media/sf_P_DRIVE/FileMonitor/", 0, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);

    int ret = WaitForSingleObject(m_EventID, 10000);
    printf("\nFinish %d", ret);
    fflush(stdout);

    FindNextChangeNotification(m_EventID);

    int ret2 = WaitForSingleObject(m_EventID, 10000);
    printf("\nFinish %d", ret2);

    FindCloseChangeNotification(1);
    printf("\nChangeNotification done");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

If you prefer to do it yourself try to use the poll function, you can use it inside of a thread.

```
        struct pollfd pfd = { th_params->fd, POLLIN, 0 };
        int ret = poll(&pfd, 1, 50);  // timeout of 50ms
        if (ret < 0) {
            printf("\failed poll");


        }
        else if (ret == 0) {
            // Timeout with no events, move on.
            printf("\nTimeout poll");

        }
        else {

            i = 0;
            int lenght = read(th_params->fd, buffer, 1024);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void FilesListener::refresh()
{
    char buffer[1024];

    int length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
    if ( length >=0 ) 
    {  
    ....
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14129596)

Comment: well I got no better answer nor informations, so help yourself

Comment: If select() is removed, read() will also block the thread. Passing a struct timeval to select will unblock it and select() will return 0 if it's just a timeout with no new data from the file descriptor. https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-ubuntu-inotify/#tips-for-using-inotify